# Play Console 2021 promote release from Beta to Production missing

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have released an app to Beta in the Play Console and would like to promote it to production, however when I go to the Beta release and click Promote release nothing happens, there is no drop down to select from.

This worked when promoting from internal to open testing, what am I missing?

[image: play console]

Comment: Do you have a draft release in production?

Comment: Nope, I have nothing in production. I have one internal test release and the open testing release.

Answer (score 0):

Play console (2022)

1.Go to Releases

2.Go to Production

3.Click Edit Releases

4.click Add from library

it will lists all unpublished app bundles or apk ,
select your internal test build from them.